# ES6 - Super required in constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
class Overflow {}
class Stack extends Overflow {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

let stack = new Stack();
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/JqRfuDAav9opvapwCGpT?p=preview

If I use `construtor()` I **must** call super() **always**.

Why isn't `super()` auto called in constructor?

Edit: Is `super()` here calling the base `constructor`  **AND** setting the prototype? Seems wrong.
Edit: Why is `super()` required? Even when I've no intention of calling the base constructor.

Comment: *"Why isn't `super()` auto called in constructor?"* Which arguments should be passed to it? None, all or a subset? Any decision would probably lead to a discussion why that approach was chosen and not another...

Comment: The call to `super()` is required **always**. Try to write a valid ES6 constructor without `super()`.

Comment: I know... I don't understand what you are trying to tell me with your comment.

Comment: *"Why is `super()` required? Even when I've no intention of calling the base constructor."* Because `this` needs to be initialized properly (i.e. the object generated by calling the constructor needs to be constructed properly). That is primarily a concern for extending exotic objects / classes, such as `Array`.

Comment: Related: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/not-forcing-super-in-derived-class-s-constructor

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you for this link. Really. From this link I read link after link. I had some backgrounds missing.

Comment: My understanding now is: the call to `super()` is required because you **MAY** use the `this` of base class. More like a safety reason.

Comment: BUT, if you don't use `this` at all. Your base class don't need to be a base class, lol. Now I get it.

Comment: Not just that. The whole purpose of `new X()` is to create a new object. The caller will definitely use that object. Having to call `super()` is a guarantee that the base class can initialize that object properly.

Comment: Thinking more.. This is just for safety no? I could never call the base constructor in derived, but some base method could set state `this.x = 'x'` (just like other languages). Perhaps not the best practice.

Comment: *"I could never call the base constructor in derived"* If you have a custom `constructor` you have to call `super()`. If you don't have a custom `constructor`, the base constructor will be called automatically.

Comment: In the current ES6, yes. But why this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144920/es6-super-required-in-constructor?noredirect=1#comment61830517_37144920

Comment: This was a spec for the keyword `class`. The old way, in ES5, can allow you to call the "construtor" without calling the base one. Why this is the standard in a sugar syntax?

Comment: In ES5 it wasn't possible to extend exotic objects like `Array`. As I said, this enforcement is primarily because of exotic objects. In ES5, calling `new X` is basically the same as `X.call(Object.create(X.prototype))`, i.e. it would simply generate a generic object and pass that to the constructor. But arrays are not simply objects and they cannot be created before the constructor function is called (because it is not known at that moment how exactly to create them). Hence it has to be done inside the constructor itself, via `super()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28224044/4341575

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axel FTW
http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html

#### Summary

Why super is required?

- The new keyword `class` isn't just syntax sugar.
- Allocation and instantiation only happens in the base constructor.

But why this?

- To allow exotic objects to be extended (thank you Felix Kling).

Answer (score 4):

> Why isn't `super()` auto called in constructor?

So you can decide *where* in the constructor to call it. This is perfectly valid, for instance:

```
constructor(foo) {
    let bar;
    if (foo) {
        bar = /*...*/;
    } else {
        bar = /*...*/;
    }
    super(bar);
}
```

...provided no code prior to the call to `super` uses `this` (or `super.xyz`).

Yes, it would have been possible to define the language such that if you didn't have any call to `super` in your constructor *at all*, it was added automatically for you at the beginning (a'la Java), but they just decided not to do it that way.

> Is `super()` here calling the base constructor AND setting the prototype? Seems wrong.

No, it's calling the base constructor. The prototype was set before your constructor was called. It's exactly like this old ES5 code:

```
function Derived() {
    Base.call(this);
}
```

...in:

```
function Base() {
}

function Derived() {
    Base.call(this);
}
Derived.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
Derived.prototype.constructor = Derived;
```

> Why is `super()` required? Even when I've no intention of calling the base constructor.

If you have no intention of calling the base constructor, then your subclass isn't a subclass and shouldn't be extending the base. In a strictly-typed language you'd probably make the base (or a subset of the base) an interface and have your class implement that rather than subclassing. In JavaScript, no need, just make it quack like the duck you want it to be. If an `instanceof` relationship is important, create a new base that will act like an interface but doesn't do anything anywhere, and have the old base and your class subclass it directly.

Comment: Is `super()` here calling the base `constructor()` AND setting the prototype? Seems wrong that I'm required to call a `super()` I didn't asked.

Comment: Perhaps my question is more towards to **why** calling the `super()` is required.

Comment: It isn't strictly required. You could also `return` something, so if it auto-added `super()` at the beginning, you'd be doing extra work. It's also not quite exactly like the ES5 code though, as `this` is uninitialized until you've called `super()` so there isn't even an object to have a prototype yet.

Comment: @old: It is required to correctly initialize `this`. If you think it should be called implicitly, which arguments should be passed to it?