# TypeScript: index signature is missing with ArrayLike interface

Tags: typescript

I tried to use TypeScript built-in interface, `ArrayLike`, but still got the error message like following:

> Error:(12, 11) TS2420: Class 'Point' incorrectly implements interface 'ArrayLike'. Index signature is missing in type 'Point'.

```
interface ArrayLike<T> {
    length: number;
    [n: number]: T;
}

class Point implements ArrayLike<number> {
    [0]: number = 10;
    length: number = 1;
}
```

How can I solve this problem? (or any workaround?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to implement the interface `ArrayLike`:

```
class Point implements ArrayLike<number> {
    [n: number]: number;
    length: number = 1;
    [0]: number = 10;
}

let p = new Point()
p[23] = 34; // ok
p[23] = "34"; // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

Comment: Am I correct that in your answer `[n: number]: number;` is not required? So the correct implementation is `class Point implements ArrayLike<number> {
    length: number = 1;
    [0]: number = 10;
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `Point` to be an array then why not just extending the `Array` class?

```
class Point extends Array<number> {
    // add Point array methods here
}
```

This way `Point` will implement the `ArrayLike<number>` interface automatically.

Comment: Fyi, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700164/extending-array-with-es6-classes#28224044

Comment: @Paleo Interesting, though I still haven't encountered any issues with extending the `Array` class. Also, why would you want to set the length of the array directly? It makes little sense.

Comment: Sincerely, I don't know why to use the interface `ArrayLike<T>`. I just answered to the question. :s

Comment: @Paleo I don't want to inherit all methods in Array due to the responsibility of the class.